# Embedding cab files into msi

Tags: windows-installer

Hi I am trying to use the msidb.exe to embed a cabinet file into my MSI like so:

```
msidb.exe -d Setup.msi -a file.cab
```

When I open the MSI in InstEd I can see it in the _streams table but in Orca it is not getting added to the media table.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msidb.exe doesn't update the media table, it only updates streams.  You have to author the media table (and other tables)  yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I do this and I still get the error `DEBUG: Error 2356:  Couldn't locate cabinet in stream: media1.cab.`

Comment: How are you building your MSI?  If you're using wix you can set  EmbedCab="yes" inside your <Media> element.